# rspec rails 6 controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have created a new project using rails 6 and I can't test many controllers with rspec 3.8 or 3.9.0.pre, for example this test:

```rb
it 'OK' do
  get :index
  expect(response).to be_ok
end
```

raises

```
Failure/Error: render template: 'rig_masters/index'

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

if I have a controller that renders **json** it passes, for example if the controller is

```rb
def index
  @components = Component.recent
  render json: @components
end
```

test passes

but if I try to render a view like

```rb
def index
  @components = Component.recent
end
```

or even

```rb
def index
  @components = Component.recent
  render template: 'components/index'
end
```

raises the `ActionView::Template::Error: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)` error

Any help to make these tests pass would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey @Boris, do you have this in your RSpec configuration `config.render_views` ?

Comment: No, but when I upgraded to rspec-rails 4.0.0.beta2 the errors dissapeared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RSpec isn't compatible with Rails 6 yet.
However, you can use rspec-rails 4.0.0.beta2, which will fix this particular issue!

Link: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2155

Answer (score 5):

I checked issue gets fixed with this version:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta2'
```